# Where do I handle the initial value before the first onChange(of:)?

Tags: swiftui

I want to load some data when my app is first launched, and when the app is **foregrounded** I want to ensure I have the latest data.

The state is stored in a ViewModel class, which my view owns as a `@StateObject`. I read the `ScenePhase` from the Environment, and in `onChange(of: scenePhase)`, I call a method on my ViewModel to start the reload if needed.

But when should I start the *initial* load?

- `ContentView.init` is too early, because `scenePhase` is `.background`. And even if it were `.active`, I'm apparently not supposed to access StateObject from init — SwiftUI logs a runtime warning.
- `ViewModel.init` is too early as well — theoretically, I think the view model could be created even if the app were never brought to the foreground.
- The first time `var body` is accessed, the scenePhase is `.active`. `onChange(of:)` doesn't call the closure for its initial value, so it's never called until I background and re-foreground the app.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  init() {
    // 1. reload() here? Could happen without the app entering the foreground.
  }

  func reload() { ... }
}


struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
  @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

  init() {
    // 2. viewModel.reload() here?
    //  - problem 1: scenePhase == .background, not .active
    //  - problem 2: not supposed to access a @StateObject here anyway
  }

  var body: some View {
    (...)
      // The initial render happens when scenePhase == .active,
      // so I don't get the onChange callback until it changes again.
      .onChange(of: scenePhase) {
        if $0 == .active {
          viewModel.reload()
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `.onAppear()` - this happens when the view is first added (or re-added) to the view hierarchy

Comment: Doesn't `onAppear` also get called when the view becomes visible again after being hidden (e.g. in a navigation stack)?

Comment: When navigating back? I don't believe so

Comment: @NewDev I think it depends on the device, on iPhones `onAppear` will be called again, on iPads it won't.

Comment: @pawello2222, just tried on an iPhone simulator, with `.onAppear` attached to `NavigationView` it doesn't fire on back. With it attached to something inside it, it fires multiple times

Comment: @NewDev Yes, you're right. Thanks :) Initially I thought as you but then I ran my own tests... (I must have attached onAppear in the wrong place by mistake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 17.0+, macOS 14.0+, etc., there is a new `onChange` that supports an initial parameter.

[`onchange(of:initial:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:initial:_:)-4psgg)

```swift
.onChange(of: focusState, initial: true) { (oldState, newState) in
    // Will run when the view appears
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `ContentView` is the root View you can just use `onAppear`.

---

However, if your `ContentView` can disappear and then reappear the above solution will not work.

A possible solution may be to inject a variable into the Environment:

```
struct LaunchAppKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue = Binding.constant(false)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isAppLaunched: Binding<Bool> {
        get { return self[LaunchAppKey] }
        set { self[LaunchAppKey] = newValue }
    }
}
```

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @State private var isAppLaunched = false
    @State private var showContentView = true
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                if showContentView {
                    ContentView()
                } else {
                    Text("Some other view")
                }
            }
            .environment(\.isAppLaunched, $isAppLaunched)
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                    showContentView.toggle()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6) {
                    showContentView.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.isAppLaunched) var isAppLaunched
    
    var body: some View {
        (...)
        .onAppear {
            guard !isAppLaunched.wrappedValue else { return }
            isAppLaunched.wrappedValue = true
            print("apppear")
        }
    }
}
```